# Can not access session in command line php script using SSH

Tags: php, session, cookies, ssh

When users login to my site their sessions starts. I want to access these session values in my command line script.
I can get PHPSESSID cookie value and then i used these line to get session value

```
session_id($session);
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
```

Here **$session** variable contains the PHPSESSID cookie value.
When i am running this script on my local server (xampp) , it is working. I can easily access session value for any PHPSESSID.

**Poblem**
When i moved my site to web server, it stopped working.
 I purchase a **VPS** hosting plan on godaddy and make an account for new domain using WHM panel. I run my command line php script  using **SSH (putty)**.

Now i can not read session value by `$_SESSION['user_name']`(for example). I am not allowed to read session in this command line script. Is there any way to access these session values over here.

Comment: command line no web server= no sessions

Comment: I understand but i am using this coomand line script as a websocket server so i can receive cookie value during handshaking process of websocket protocol and after putting the cookie value in session_id() function i can access that session value in my local server but on webserver??

Comment: This method is also working on my wifi network, i think the problem is with web server session permission or something like that. If you have any suggestion please tell me